# iOS any way to modify push notification alert message once received?

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios10

My server yields push notifications with a payload including `loc-key` and `loc-args`, then when a message is received in the app it displays a notification based on the contents of `Localizable.strings` filling `loc-key` template with the content of `loc-args`.

I'd like to do some post processing for the content of the displayed notification, e.g. access user's address book locally and match a phone number to a contact name, and then display an updated alert while the app is running the background. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a silent push notification (`content-available = 1`) which will be delivered to [`application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application) and then use the information in the push notification to create and display a local notification.

The only drawback with this approach is that your application delegate method won't be called if the user has terminated your app (swipe up from app switcher).

Answer (score 0):

If app is in foreground you can catch and process the notification, but if the app is in background or the app is not running you have no access to the notification data.